# Creating instance variable on instance create without using the `initialize` method

Tags: ruby

In the example below, I want to have an instance variable in class `B` that is created/set whenever `B` is instantiated. Obviously I don't want to have to go redefine all the `initialize` methods of `A`.

```
class A

  def initialize(a)
  end

  def initialize(a, b)
  end

end

class B < A
  # Here I want an instance variable created without
  # redefining the initialize methods

  @iv = "hey" #<-- Obviously does not work

  # And I don't want to have to do @iv |= "hey" all over the place

end
```

Comment: You do understand that `A` only has one `initialize` method, right? The second one overrides the first one.

Comment: Hmm, no, I didn't, but I see now that there is no method overloading in Ruby.

Comment: That sort of makes the problem go away, no? Since there is only one `initialize`, there's no problem.

Comment: By the way: the code snippet you posted will generate a `warning: method redefined; discarding old initialize`. You should really read those warnings. They are there to, you know, warn you about potential problems with your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you have against defining initialize methods, but this is how it should be done.

```
class A
  def initialize a
    @a = a
  end

  attr_accessor :a
end

class B < A
  def initialize a, b
    @b = b
    super(a)
  end
  attr_accessor :b
end

b = B.new 1, 2

b.a # => 1
b.b # => 2
```

Comment: Sorry, the reason is a lack of understanding on my part. As mu is too short points out, there is no method overloading, so my example is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, that confused me too. I should have pointed this out also :)

Comment: Sergio is completely right that this is standard practice that you should use all the time.